# how to get size of list value of map by streams in java

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to group a list of strings by the **length**.
and then I want to get count of each group.
and I did the first one and I can't do the next.
how can I fix my code with streams?

```
Stream.of(Stream.of("Brad","Jack","Leonardo","Alexander","Juliet","William","Audrey")
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length)))
                .forEach(System.out::print);
```

output:
{4=[Brad, Jack], 6=[Juliet, Audrey], 7=[William], 8=[Leonardo], 9=[Alexander]}

the next thing that I want to get is count of each group.
How can I do that?

Comment: I'm assuming you did not intend to have two nested Stream.of in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain `Collectors.counting()`:

```
Map<Integer,Long> counts = 
   Stream.of("Brad","Jack","Leonardo","Alexander","Juliet","William","Audrey")
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length,
                                        Collectors.counting()));
```

This will produce the following `Map`:

```
{4=2, 6=2, 7=1, 8=1, 9=1}
```